# "OR " condition in where clause of linq query is returning null

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The following code when executed individually is executing properly but when an or condition is included 
 to club both the condition in single query its returning null

```
userSessionList = userSessionList.Where(u => 
            (u.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(name)) || 
            (u.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(name))
        )
        .ToList();
```

Comment: An `||` cannot filter out matches that existed prior to it. It can only add matches. It can introduce an exception though which may be hidden by your `catch()` that does nothing, such as a `NullReferenceException` on `u.User.LastName.ToLower()`.

Comment: yes I am getting object NullReferenceException. Can you please suggest how to write this query exactly.

Comment: `yes I am getting object NullReferenceException` - would have been very helpful if you mentioned that in the question instead of saying the query is returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

```
userSessionList = userSessionList.Where(u => 
            (u.User?.FirstName?.ToLower().Contains(name) == true) || 
            (u.User?.LastName?.ToLower().Contains(name) == true)
        )
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this and see if it works:

```
   userSessionList = userSessionList.Where(u => 
        (u.User != null && u.User.FirstName != null && u.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(name)) || 
        (u.User != null && u.User.LastName != null && u.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(name))
    )
    .ToList();
```

You can also run for testing purposes the following in the same execution and see the results

```
    var userSessionList1 = userSessionList.Where(u => 
        (u.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(name))
    )
    .ToList();

    var userSessionList2 = userSessionList.Where(u => 
        (u.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(name))
    )
    .ToList();

    var userSessionListBoth = userSessionList.Where(u => 
        (u.User.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(name)) || 
        (u.User.LastName.ToLower().Contains(name))
    )
    .ToList();
```

And check the three different list. I think that because you are overriding the existing list, it might be that you have done it again in a previous query and that's why you have this weird situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot checking for the null condition worked.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [String.IndexOf Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_StringComparison_) and pass [StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_StringComparer_OrdinalIgnoreCase) as the type of search to use:

```
culture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(u.User.LastName, name, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0
```

Comment: Thank you but I am concerned about returning list of users which matches given condition

Comment: @ManjunathM.R And this tries to show you how to do it correctly, without involving `ToLower`.